# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' in VS code

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pip

im trying to run this

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from matplotlib import plypot as plt
import time 
import mediapipe as mp
```

and also

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():

    #Reads feed
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.inshow('OpenCV feed', frame)
   
    #breaks for a while
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):

        break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

in  vscode the first one gives me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' and the second code gives me NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined.

here is a picture of my opencv requirements
[image]

i tried `pip install opencv-python`

[image] but all the requirement were met

Comment: You must have several versions of Python installed on your system. `pip` installed the package for one version, but VS Code is configured to use a different version.

Comment: Often - especially when suspecting dependencies - it's recommended to use a virtual environment. That allows to eliminate such issues by isolating each project's dependencies.
`python3 -m venv`

Comment: thank you, when i uninstalled a previous version of python it worked. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pip3 install opencv-python`, as it installs opencv for python3, not python2 (if you have it installed). If you only have python3, pip and pip3 are basically the same thing (I think).